# Building Intel Threading Building Blocks fails with Mingw-w64

Tags: c++, build, mingw-w64, tbb

I am using Mingw-w64 with gcc 10.2 and I am trying to compile Intel Threading Building Blocks on a MSYS2 console. I have been successfully using the build scripts of the older versions before, but the new version with tag "v2021.2.0" offers CMake build only.

I build by running this script on the MSYS2 console:

```
#!/bin/bash

TBB_DIR=/c/Libraries/TBB
PARALLEL_PROCESSES=1

echo
echo Building Tbb...
echo
rm -rf $TBB_DIR/Build
mkdir $TBB_DIR/Build
cd $TBB_DIR/Build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" -S "$TBB_DIR" -B "$TBB_DIR/Build" -G "MSYS Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="$TBB_DIR/Install" -DTBB_STRICT=False -DTBB_TEST=False
cd $TBB_DIR/Build
mingw32-make -j $PARALLEL_PROCESSES install
```

The builds fails and the error is:

```
In file included from C:/Libraries/TBB/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_utils.h:26,
                 from C:/Libraries/TBB/src/tbb/allocator.cpp:21:
C:/Libraries/TBB/include/oneapi/tbb/detail/_machine.h:241:56: error: '_MCW_DN' was not declared in this scope
  241 |     static constexpr unsigned int X87CW_CONTROL_MASK = _MCW_DN | _MCW_EM | _MCW_RC;
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Why is this the case? Is Mingw-w64 not supported? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_MCW_DN` is in the `float.h` [header file](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/master/tree/mingw-w64-headers/crt/float.h#l147), so it should work.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you specify the wrong makefile flavor. You want `"MinGW Makefiles"`, **or** switch to `make` instead of `mingw32-make`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am using a UNIX shell (MSYS2). Therefore I have to use "MSYS Makefiles" as far as I know. If I try to use "MINGW Makefiles" I get this error message: ```sh.exe was found in your PATH, here: ... For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path. Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH. If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.```

Comment: @ssbssa Interesting... In my installation there is an additional line ```#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__``` before the control word masks, which prevents their definition. If I compile with an additional option ```-U__STRICT_ANSI__```, I get another compilation error: ```TBB/src/tbb/co_context.h:135:9: error: 'IsThreadAFiber' was not declared in this scope```. I wonder whether there have been many people yet, who have built v2021.* with MinGW-w64...?

Comment: There is an open pull request in oneTBB considering mingw support: https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/pull/351.

Comment: The `__STRICT_ANSI__` checks were only [very recently removed](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mingw-w64/ci/c6e13e0c105eab7797c2373819b49fff6b05566c/). And `__STRICT_ANSI__` is only defined if you a base standard, like `-std=c11`, but not if you use a GNU dialect, like `-std=gnu11`.

Comment: @ssbssa If I set ```-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-std=gnu++11``` when calling CMake, then still the compilation command additionally contains ```-std=c++11``` at the end. This options seems to be added somewhere in the build system. Therefore the error message stays the same.

Comment: Does the cmake file contain `set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`? This would [disable the GNU dialect](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS.html).

Comment: *"Therefore I have to use "MSYS Makefiles""* Then you probably want to use `make` instead of `mingw32-make`. Not sure how much it matters though.

Comment: @ssbssa You are right, it contains ```CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS``` and changing it changes the GNU dialect. But then the other compilation error appears. I will wait until they have completed mingw support. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm able to build [TBB 2020.0](https://github.com/intel/tbb/archive/v2020.0.tar.gz) with MinGW-w64 on Windows like this (without CMake):

```
#ARCH=ia32
ARCH=intel64
mingw32-make compiler=gcc arch=$ARCH runtime=mingw tbb tbbmalloc CPLUS="g++ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc"
```

Comment: The question has been explicitly about the new version v2021.*.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that there was a newer version.
I also have issues building 2021.2.0: issues related to Unicode + 87 stuff (like `error: '_control87' was not declared in this scope`)